# Seeking periodic solutions with Fourier

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

So I am looking to find the solutions of : $$-u''+u=\cos(6x)$$
I did go through all the usual stages: Fourier transform, inversion theorem (since the resulting $\hat u \in L^1)$, then Jordan lemma + Residue theorem to calculate the inverse transform and as you would expect I end up with the solution in terms of a convolution.

The problem is that the answer I am provided is completely different, and the hint tells me to use the "method for researching periodic solutions through the Fourier series". I'm not sure what that entails, so I would really appreciate if someone could guide me through it.

Thank you.

Comment: They are telling you to use the Fourier series, not Fourier transform.  Since $\cos(6x)$ has period $\pi/3$, you could try to find a solution of the DE which also has period $\pi/3$.

Comment: True, that was a silly oversight on my part. I get what you're saying, but what exactly is this "method" that is being hinted? How do I use the Fourier series to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way is to try a solution in the form
$$
u=A\sin(6x)+B\cos(6x).
$$
Putting this into the equation you will get
$$
36A\sin(6x)+36B\cos(6x)+A\sin(6x)+B\cos(6x)=\cos(6x).
$$
This will give you a system of two equations in two unknowns for $A$ and $B$.

For a Fourier series, one has to write
$$
u(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{i2\pi n x}.
$$
By a direct substitution this gives
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty 2\pi n^2 a_ne^{i2\pi n x}+\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{i2\pi n x}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-i6x}+\frac{1}{2}e^{i6x}.
$$
We can invert this by multiplying with $e^{-i2\pi mx}$ and integrating between $0$ and $2\pi$ yielding
$$
(2\pi m^2+1)a_m=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2i\pi mx}e^{6ix}+\frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{-2i\pi mx}e^{-6ix}.
$$
This can be easily worked out to obtain $a_m$.

Comment: Only problem is that this is the classic way of dealing with a DE. It doesn't go through the Fourier series which is what I'm asked to do. But yes, this is of course the result so it's a nice confirmation.

Comment: This works fine.  It is what I would do.  But the OP says his hint was to use the Fourier series.

Comment: I think I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to find a particular solution of 
$$
-u''+u=\cos(6x)
\tag1$$
Since $\cos(6x)$ has period $\pi/3$, let's see if there is a solution also with period $\pi/3$.  This proposed solution would have Fourier series
$$
u(x) = a_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \big(a_k\cos(6kx)+b_k\sin(6kx)\big)
$$
Now
$$
u'(x) =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\big( -6ka_k\sin(6kx)+6kb_k\cos(6kx)\big)
\\
u''(x) =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\big( -36ka_k\cos(6kx)-36kb_k\sin(6kx)\big)
$$
Then we get
$$
-u''(x)+u(x) = 
a_0+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty\big((a_k-36ka_k)\cos(6kx)+(-36kb_k+b_k)\sin(6kx)\big)
$$
This is supposed to equal $\cos(6x)$, so we equate coefficients.  $a_0 = 0$.  For $k > 1$ we get
$$
(a_k-36ka_k)=0,\quad (-36kb_k+b_k)=0
$$
so $a_k = 0, b_k = 0$.  Finally, for $k=1$ we get
$$
a_1-36a_1 = 1,\quad -36b_1+b_1=0
$$
so $a_1 = -1/35, b_1 = 0$.  Our solution is $-\cos(6x)/35$.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you very much both of you for your precious input. I also found something myself that I'd like to add to the table, albeit I'm not entirely sure I'm using it correctly.

Clearly, $T=\pi/3$. Let's now consider $\xi_k=k{2\pi \over T}=6k$

We have that the characteristic polynomial of the DE is: $P(\lambda)=-\lambda^2+1$

Now we observe that $P(i\xi_k)=-(i\xi_k)^2+1=36k^2+1\not=0 $ for $k\in Z$

So the equation has a solution of period $\pi/3$ given by: $$\hat u_k={c_k \over 36k^2+1}$$with $c_k$ being the Fourier coefficients of $cos(6x)$ given by the general formula $$c_k={1\over T} \int_0^Tf(x)e^{-i{2\pi \over T}kx}dx=$$

$${3 \over \pi}\int_0^{\pi \over3}cos(6x)e^{-i6kx}dx={3 \over \pi}\int_0^{\pi \over3}{e^{i6x}+e^{-i6x} \over 2}e^{-i6kx}dx=$$

$$={3\over 2\pi}\int_0^{\pi \over 3}e^{i6x(1-k)}+e^{-i6x(1+k)}={3\over 2\pi}\biggl(\bigg[{e^{i6x(1-k)}\over i6(1-k)} \bigg]_0^{\pi\over 3}-\bigg[{e^{-i6x(1+k)}\over -i6(1+k)} \bigg]_0^{\pi\over 3}\bigg)...$$

and so on - I'm not gonna write all the math since it would take ages. In essence, that seems to  be the Fourier transform of $cos(6x)$ using as variable the initial $\xi_k=k{2\pi \over T}=6k$. Eventually we reach: $$c_{k}={1\over 2} \rightarrow k=\pm1$$ $$c_{k}=0 \rightarrow k\not=\pm1$$ 
And we finally get to the solution given by $$u(x)={1 \over 2(36k^2+1)}(e^{6x}+e^{-6x})={1\over 37}cos(6x)$$

Again, I'm not entirely certain of the legality of this method, but at least the result seems to be correct so that's something...